# Eilenberg-Steenrod Axioms for covariant functors on $Top^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

$Top^2$ is a category of all pairs of topological spaces $(X,A)$ where $A$ is a subspace of $X$. The morphism in this category is $(X,A)\to (X',A')$ with $Im(A)\subset A'$. Denote $\phi$ as the empty set.

a) Why would one even consider pairs of topological spaces first place? Shouldn't $Top$ category is more natural to be considered instead?

There are 4 axioms required for covariant functors $G_n:Top^2\to Ab$.

1. Requirement of homotopy axiom is clear as homology functor $H_n:Top\to Ab$ does not distinguish homotopies.
2. Exactness Axiom: Write $G_n(X,\phi)$. Any pair of $(X,A)$ has $i:(A,\phi)\to (X,\phi)$ and $j:(X,\phi)\to (X,A)$ with $i,j$ canonical injection maps. There is a long exact sequence $\cdots\to G_{n+1}(X,A)\to G_n(A,\phi)\to G_n(X,\phi)\to G_n(X,A)\to\cdots $

I think $j$ is also surjective map as $(X,\phi)\to (X,A)$ is basically $id_X:X\to X$ map. So that long exact sequence comes from $(A,\phi)\to (X,\phi)\to (X,A)$.

b) Is $(X,\phi)$ treated as the projective object here?

c) Normally I would have long exact sequence induced from a short exact sequence in some $Ab$ category. $Top^2$ is not $Ab$ category. How should I understand the induced long exact sequence? Clearly I have initial object in $Top^2$ by $(\phi,\phi)$

3. Excision Axiom. Given a pair $(X,A)$ and $U\subset X$ with $\bar{U}\subset interior(A)$, the inclusion $(X-U,A-U)\to (X,A)$ induces isomorphism $G_n(X-U,A-u)\to G_n(X,A)$ for all $n\geq 0$.

d) Why would one want $\bar{U}\subset interior(A)$ rather than $U\subset interior(A)$? Where is isomorphism orginally coming from or what is the motivation that one wants isomorphism on $G_n(X-U,A-U)\to G_n(X,A)$?

4. Dimension Axiom. For every one-point space $P$, we have $G_n(P)=Z$ for $n=0$ $0$ other wise which is clear.

Comment: I think if you study Chapter 2 in Hatcher a lot of these questions will be answered.

Comment: @AreaMan Thanks for the reference. It seems reading purely homological algebra requires algebraic topology at some time point.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You will be missing a lot of important intuitions if you try to learn homological algbera without studying algebraic topology. (Also Topology is so beautiful, why wouldn't you study it.) If you have background in homological algbera it will certainly make learning topology easier (the topics that confused me when I was learning algebraic topology for the first time made a lot more sense after I studied some abstract homological algebra and derived functors).

Comment: (The homological algebra constructions like "mapping cone, mapping cylinder, homotopy" all come from topology, and the boundary map in the LES has a good topological interpretation, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) one motivation is the pair $(X,A)$ acts somewhat like the quotient $X/A$ and this quotient along with the subspace $A$ may be better understood then axiom 2 gives us a way to study $X$. For example when $A$ is such that $H_n(X,A)$ vanishes we have the isomorphism $H_n(A) \approx H_n(X)$.

B) $(X,\phi)$ is not necessarily projective here. If it were then for morphism $f:(X,\phi) \rightarrow (Y,\phi)$ and epimorphism $q:(Z,\phi) \twoheadrightarrow (Y,\phi)$ and $f$ factors through $q$. But any morphism in **Top** can be realized as a morphism of the form $(X,\phi ) \rightarrow (Y,\phi)$ in **Top**$^2$ so $X$ is projective in **Top** for all $X$ which is not necessarily true.

C) The long exact sequence is in **Ab** as we have the functor $G_n:\mathbf{Top}^2\rightarrow  \mathbf{Ab}$.

D) Excision can stated equivalently for subspaces $A,B \subset X$ whose interiors cover $X$ the inclusion $(B, A \cap B) \hookrightarrow (X,A)$ induces isomorphisms $G_n(B,A\cap B)\rightarrow G_n(X,A)$. The covering of $X$ by interiors seems more natural and is equivalent to the closure $\bar U \subset int \, A$.